# Convergence of the areas of inscribed squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, limits

As kind of usual, I want to see if my solution for a problem is correct. Any feedback will be more than welcome, and alternative solutions are always great to receive.

Take a square with an arbitrary side of $a>1$. Then, to each side, find a point that is 1 unit away from one extreme. Do this in such a way that an inscribed square is generated. The following image shows the first step of the process, where: 
$$|DE|=|CF|=|BG|=|AH|=1$$
[image]

The question is, **what can we say about the sum of the areas of all squares obtained if the process continues as long as it can be?**

The thing is, the process can continue infinitely since the next side of the square is always a little more than 1. If $l_n$ is the side length of the $n-th$ square, then:
$$l_{n+1}=\sqrt{(l_n-1)^2+1}$$
Clearly, the sequence of all the sides of the squares is decreasing, since evidently the squares are inscribed within the previous, and also, is composed of positve numbers so is bounded from below by $0$. Then, we can claim that the sequence converges (since is bounded and monotone). Let the limit of the sequence be $L$. Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} l_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} l_n$$
so $L=\sqrt{(L-1)^2+1}$, then $L=1$. Which means means, the resulting inscribed squares in the process will have side lengths arbitrarily close to 1.
If the sum of all the areas is denoted by $S_n$, then:
$$S_n \ge \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1=\infty$$

Wich means, $S_n$ does not converge.

The key fact of the argument is that the process can always continue, since the sides obtained are always $\varepsilon>0$ units greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument looks good. I would just clean up the last bit

$S_n \geq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1 = \infty$

to

$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (l_i)^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$

$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty$

so it diverges